# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: mapster is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a map selection and I'm using mapster but when I run I get this error

// a cross reference of area names to text to be shown for each area
    var xref = {
        Flamborough: 'Flamborough, OntarioPopulation: 22,333',
        Dundas: 'Dundus, OntarioPopulation: 24,702',
        Acanster: 'Ancaster, OntarioPopulation: 33,000',
        Glanbrook: 'Glanbrook, OntarioPopulation: 77,774',
        StoneyCreek: 'Stoney Creek, OntarioPopulation: 62,292',
        Hamilton: 'Hamilton, OntarioPopulation: 490, 268'
    };

```
var image = $("#hamilton_map");

image.mapster(
{
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    fillColor: "d42e16",
    stroke: true,
    strokeColor: "3320FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    singleSelect: true,
    mapKey: 'name',
    listKey: 'name',
    onClick: function (e) {
        // update text depending on area selected
        $('#selections').html(xref[e.key]);


            areas: [
                {
                    key: "Flamborough",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                },
                {
                    key: "Dundas",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                },
                {
                    key: "Acanster",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                },
                {
                    key: "Glanbrook",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                },
                {
                    key: "Hamilton",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                },
                {
                    key: "StoneyCreek",
                    fillColor: "EE82EE"
                }
            ]
    }
});
```

This what I have

Comment: You haven't included the jquery mapster plugin code in your page.

Comment: or it is included after you attempt to call it, or you have more than one version of jQuery being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, I just add this to my Js function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').mapster(initial_opts)
.mapster('set',true,'CA', {
    fill: true,
    fillColor: '00ff00'
})
.mapster('snapshot')
.mapster('rebind',basic_opts);
```

});

```js
    var image = $("#hamilton_map");
    $(document).ready(function() {
    image.mapster(
    {
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        fillColor: "d42e16",
        stroke: true,
        strokeColor: "3320FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        singleSelect: true,
        mapKey: 'name',
        listKey: 'name',
        onClick: function (e) {
            // update text depending on area selected
            $('#selections').html(xref[e.key]);


                areas: [
                    {
                        key: "Flamborough",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Dundas",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Acanster",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Glanbrook",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "Hamilton",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    },
                    {
                        key: "StoneyCreek",
                        fillColor: "EE82EE"
                    }
                ]
        }
    })
    });
```